# The correct syntax for 'await' in a conditional statement

Tags: c#, asynchronous

what is the correct syntax for await in a conditional statement?

is it

```
if( !await MyFunctionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) )
{
   ...
}
```

or is it

```
if( !(await MyFunctionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) )
{
   ...
}
```

The reason I ask is because it looks like I am doing `!await` rather than `!(await MyFunctionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))` and I am concerned that the syntax in invalid...

Or is it just cosmetic and all up to the developer?

Comment: Pretty much cosmetic. I think the easiest to read would be `var gotSomething = await MyFunctionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); if (!gotSomething) { ... }`.

Comment: yess, it just cosmetic

Comment: When you tried to compile both did you get any syntax errors? Since the answer is "no" your questions is clearly about preferences which is "opinion based"... If you want you can find question about priority of operations in C# to use as duplicate target.

Comment: Yes I tried, and no it did not give any errors, having said that, it the code compile it does not always mean that it does what it is supposed to do. In c++ the code `if( a = 1){....}` would compile with no errors but so would `if( a == 1){....}`

Comment: I don't think this is a silly question at all. There are several keywords that make for some odd looking code in C#, such as inverting an `is` or `as` type coercion operator, or figuring out when to use or not use a comma when specifying multiple generic type constraints. Fortunately, like in those situations, the compiler helps you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your context, it is cosmetic.

Additionally, the `ConfigureAwait(bool)` call does have compile-time checking to make sure it is used appropriately after an `await` statement, which should give you some confidence that you are using it correctly (at least with regard to syntax).